# How to go back to last commit after detached head?

Tags: git

I don't know how exactly I did it (I think I have checkout some past commit) but I have "HEAD detached from" and I don't want that. I have only one master branch (post I read is overcomplicated about multiple branches), how do I go back to last commit without risking to wipe out all my history ?

Comment: It's hard to say but if you check `git reflog` you might have a better idea of where you are in the tree...

Comment: It sounds like you want something like `git checkout -`.